# Google Recaptcha Giving INTERNAL_ERROR on Android & IOS

Tags: android, ios, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, recaptcha-enterprise

I'm using Google recaptcha api to implement captcha on login action in my app. But every time I try to initialise the recaptcha api to get the recaptcha tasks client then It's giving either **INTERNAL_ERROR** or **Timed out waiting for 10000 ms**

I'm calling initiateSDK inside onCreate() of Application activity

Please let me know what's the reason for these errors and solution to fix.

In iOS, we are using same approach.

Code Snippet

```
public void initiateSDK(Context context) {
        if (recaptchaTasksClient == null) {
            init(context);
        }
    }

private void init(Context context) {
    new Handler().post(() -> Recaptcha.getTasksClient((Application) context.getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.RECAPTCHA_API_KEY)
        .addOnSuccessListener(client -> {
            recaptchaTasksClient = client;
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("RECAPTCHA", e.getMessage());
        }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this. What ended up being the issue was that the client initialization insisted on being done on a UI thread. The working code ended up looking something like this:

```
private fun initializeRecaptchaClient() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
      withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        Recaptcha.getClient(application, "SITE_KEY")
        .onSuccess {
            this.recaptchaClient = it
          }
          .onFailure {
            Log.e("Error initializing Recaptcha client", it)
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

The error that led to trying this solution, which only intermittently showed up was:

> E/ViewConfiguration: Tried to access UI constants from a non-visual Context:[overridden Application class]@870795fUI constants, such as display metrics or window metrics, must be accessed from Activity or other visual Context. Use an Activity or a Context created with Context#createWindowContext(int, Bundle), which are adjusted to the configuration and visual bounds of an area on screen
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tried to access UI constants from a non-visual Context:[overridden Application class]@870795f

I'm very much not entirely sure why that is. I did get the client to initialize successfully in a brand new test project without needing to force to the Main thread.

Although another cause of the "Internal Error" that I experienced while trying to get it working in the new app was forgetting the `INTERNET` permission.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This answer helped me. I was initializing recaptcha client from custom application class and I got same error. After initializing from activity onCreate and passing activity's application class to recaptcha initializer i get it working.